# Read from a file (.txt) and save into a char* C

Tags: c, file, memory

I have a file.txt that it contais, for example, "This is a txt file" (this content can be variable) and I need a function that reads file.txt and save its content into a char*.

file.txt contains -> "This is a .txt file"

and I need a char *readedContent that contains "This is a .txt file".

First, I save the content of the char *str (str contains "this is a .txt file") into a "file.txt" and then I try to get the string from this file but the string have more chars than "This is a .txt file". (Often add characters like spaces or @,?)

My function is:

```
char *special_char_remplace(char *str){


    FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("file.txt","w+"); 
    fprintf(f1,"%s", str);
    fclose(f1);

    size_t len, bytesRead;
    char *readedContent;
    FILE* f2;

    f2 = fopen("file.txt", "rb");

    fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(f2);
    rewind(f2);

    readedContent = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 1);
    readedContent[len] = '\0'; // Is needed only for printing to stdout with printf

    bytesRead = fread(readedContent, sizeof(char), len, f2);

    printf("STRING: %s\n",  readedContent);

    fclose(f2);

    return readedContent;
}
```

The problem that I have is that in the char *readedContent I have more chars than the file.txt's content.

Thanks very much.

Comment: For reading a text content you could use `fopen("file.txt", "rt");`

Comment: Can you give an example of file content versus `readedContent` your program reads?

Comment: Are you on Windows?  Are you running into a problem with ^Z (control-Z) marking the end of the file but there being up to 255 extra bytes after that to reach the end of the block?  What happens if you open the file with `"r"` or perhaps `"rt"` mode?

Comment: You might be better changing your `fread` to `fread(readedContent, len, 1, f2)` to avoid the possibility of `bytesRead` being less that `len`.  This wouldn't cause the problem you describe though.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT not quite right, "rt" is adding some extra stuff to your data (like new lines depending on OS) and not doing exact byte copy of file content

Comment: @MartinPerry But Generally I will use `rt` or `wt` for text files. Is that wrong?

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT Depends... You have to take into account, that loaded result is not byte-by-byte copy of input.

Comment: `"rt"` or `"wt"` is not recognized by the Standard. In the absence of `"b"`, the Standard says streams are opened in text mode, so `"r"` or `"w"` is correct (`"rt"` or `"wt"` is locking the program to a specific environment).

Answer (score 1):

> The problem that I have is that in the `char *readedContent` I have more chars than the `file.txt`'s content.

The most likely reason why you get more bytes than there are characters in the file is the [*encoding*](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) of your file: `fread()` reads the file byte-for-byte, so if file's encoding uses multiple bytes for some code points, your buffer is going to contain multiple bytes for one or more characters.

To verify this theory and fix the problem, write a short program that writes the bytes of your intended message, `"This is a .txt file"`, into a text file using the [`fwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fwrite.html) API. A file written in this way should read correctly with `fread()`.

Comment: The thing that I tried was:

I write a function that receive a char *string and writes into a file with fwrite(), and then I read it like I show you in the post, but it not works, when I read from the file, I have more chars than I write... I don't understand... Thanks very much

Comment: @dikerex Could you please updated the question with the code for the program that you used to write the `file.txt`'s content?

Comment: @dikerex You have an extra asterisk in front of `str` in `printf`, replace with `fprintf(f1,"%s", str);`, and the program will work as expected.

Comment: @dikerex Could you replace the last `printf` with `printf("STRING: %s %d %d\n",  readedContent, len, strlen(str));` and see what gets printed?

Comment: STRING:This is a .txt file
35 19

Comment: @dikerex That's very strange. Try one more thing - replace `fprintf` with `fwrite(str, strlen(str), 1, f1);`, and see what happens.

Comment: The lenght of the first string is less than the string that i read from the file, but I don't know...

Comment: I solve it. When I read I do this:bytesRead = fread(readedContent, sizeof(char), strlen(str), f2);
Now I read only the size of the first string.

Comment: @dikerex But you need to have the original string to do `strlen`, which beat the purpose of reading from file in the first place. Did you try my `fwrite` suggestion?

Comment: Yes I tried your fwrite suggestion and not works. The propose of the funtion is: Save a char *into a file, applicate a sed command to this file and creates a second file with the result of the sed and then read the file with the result of the sed and get a char * with the result of the sed. Maybe can be more simple that I do, but I dont know... Thanks very much...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fseek(f2, 0L, SEEK_END);
long tmpSize = ftell(f2);
fseek(f2, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

Instead of `rewind(f2)`

Also move `readedContent[len] = '\0';` after fread

Comment: According to its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) `rewind(f2)` is equivalent to `fseek(f2, 0L, SEEK_SET)`.  While I agree that moving `readedContent[len] = '\0'` might be clearer, it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: What is the benefit of not using `rewind`?  And why change the position of the assignment?

Comment: @simonc Ok... i rather use it with double fseek, Its more readable for me. I never used rewind

Comment: @Martin Perry why we shouldnt use `rewind(f2)`?

Comment: I tried it but this works exactly than before. Thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {

        char *str = "this is my file";
        FILE *f1;
        f1 = fopen("file.txt","w");
        fprintf(f1,"%s",str);
        fclose(f1);
        //string written in file.txt

        size_t len, bytesRead;
        char *readedContent;
        FILE* f2;
        f2 = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
        fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_END);
        len = ftell(f2);
        //will need it for length
        rewind(f2);
        readedContent = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 1);
        readedContent[len] = '\0'; // Is needed only for printing to stdout with printf
        bytesRead = fread(readedContent, sizeof(char), len, f2);
        //fread will read it from file and 
        //readed content will be pointed by readedContent pointer
        printf("STRING: %s\n",  readedContent);
        printf("the size is %zd\n",bytesRead);
        fclose(f2);

        return 1;
    }
```

**Output on linux**

```
 STRING: this is my file
`the size is 15`
```

*working correctly on linux*

Comment: A bit of explanation what you did would be great. Also watch formatting of your answer.

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli i am sorry,i am still new and getting familiar with the rules and culture